# ServiceStack OrmLite Text blobbed value is retrieved as null

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

We have a small application that uses ServiceStack OrmLite for database access. I am currently investigating a broken feature that worked previously.

There are two relevant entities:

```
[Alias("MyOrder")]
public class OrderEntity
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...

    // Saved as JSV blob in the table
    public AppEntity Processor { get; set; }
}

[Alias("MyApp")]
public class AppEntity
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    [StringLength(64)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public Guid? InternalUserId { get; set; }
}
```

Not sure if that matters but `AppEntity` is located in another DLL/assembly.

Now there is a strange behavior. `Processor`s are correctly saved in the table. I can also retrieve them in integration tests. However, in production code, when a list of `OrderEntity` objects is fetched, `Processor` property is null in every instance.

I digged a little bit into ServiceStack code in the debugger and saw that the JSV string is fetched correctly in the first place but it seems to get lost on the way.

This is the unit test that works:

```
var connectionString = @"Server=...";
var connectionFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, new SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider());
var orderRepository = new OrderRepository(connectionFactory);
var orders = orderRepository.FindBySomeFilter();

// entries have not-null .Processor property
```

This is a small application that doesn't work:

```
var connectionString = @"Server=...";
var connectionFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, new SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider());
var orderRepository = new OrderRepository(connectionFactory);
var orders = orderRepository.FindBySomeFilter();

// .Processor is not retrieved / null for all entries
```

Versions:

- .NET 4.5.2
- ServiceStack 5.4.0

Comment: Both code examples look exactly the same? Note: Incomplete code that can't be run locally to repro the issue isn't going to be useful to others. I'd recommend trying to put together a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that others can run to repro the issue. If you're saying it used to work, I'd be looking into when it used to work and what changed to break it. Also if you use latest [v5.4.1 on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget) it has [source link enabled](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/v5-4-1-now-hosting-source-link-enabled-packages/6728) so you can debug into fx code.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually hoping that you would take a look and might think of a direction where to look at, such as missing references. The code indeed looks the same - this is why I don't understand the difference. I will try it with 5.4.1 now and get back.

Comment: If it's the same then it suggests it may be due to environment differences, e.g. are they running the same version and did you add any new global `JsConfig` changes?  Or maybe an Exception is being swallowed, can try `JsConfig.ThrowOnError=true` to throw on error.

Comment: Same versions, however different referenced assemblies (such as XUnit in the integration test project). Projects are in the same VS solution. Failing projects are executable, working are test projects / libraries. No custom `JsConfig`, `JsConfig.ThrowOnError=true` does not throw, still `Processor` are null.

Comment: ok so it's something else, creating an isolated repro is going to be the best way to identify the issue.

Comment: Ok! I have just found that there is a swallowed exception in OrmLite. Shows a problem with manifest/assembly reference to "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.0" or a dependency. That's a good point to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things you can try for resolving runtime dependency loading issues like this where it's unable to load the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` dependency:

- Try manually adding a reference to the package, or if it's already installed try uninstalling/reinstalling it.
- Try adding `<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>` to your project

As this is is a .NET Framework project you can try adding a binding redirect:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.4.1" newVersion="4.0.4.1" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Or if you already have a binding redirect for this configured, try removing it.

Otherwise upgrading to the latest .NET Framework **v4.7+** can also resolve loading runtime system dependencies like this.

Comment: It appears that `System.Memory` in the broken application had version 4.5.1, it works with 4.5.2 now. ServiceStack seems to actually require just 4.5.1 but I assume that my library which is compiled using 4.5.2 does not work if at runtime only 4.5.1 is present. Unfortunately I am not using NuGet to reference our own libraries yet which might have avoided that...

Comment: @Tarnschaf it’s related to the same runtime loading issues, e.g. you can try a binding redirect.